# perl hashes - comparing keys and values

Tags: perl

I've been reading over the perl doc, but I can't quite get my head around hashes. I'm trying to find if a hash key exists, and if so, compare its value. The thing that is confusing me is that my searches say that you find if a key exists by `if (exists $files{$key})`, but that `$files{$key}` also gives the value? the code I'm working on is:

```
foreach my $item(@new_contents) {
    next if !-f "$directory/$item";
    my $date_modified = (stat("$directory/$item"))[9];

    if (exists $files{$item}) {
        if ($files{$item} != $date_modified {
            $files{$item} = $date_modified;
            print "$item has been modified\n";
        }
    } else {
        $files{$item} = $date_modified;
        print "$item has been added\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$files{$key}` will indeed return the value of that key. But what if that value happens to be false in a boolean context, like `0` or `''` (an empty string)?

Consider a hash like this:

```
my %foo = ( red => 42, blue => 0, green => '', yellow => undef );
```

If I were to say `if ( $foo{blue} )` the condition would fail. Even though `blue` exists in the hash, the condition is false because the value of `$foo{blue}` is zero. Same with the `green` and `yellow` keys -- empty strings and `undef` are false values.

Without `exists`, there would be no (easy) way to determine if a hash key actually is actually there and its value is false, or if it's not there at all. (You could call `keys` and then `grep` the resulting list, but that's ridiculous.)

Your code looks perfectly fine to me. You are using `exists` correctly.

Comment: @friedo I realised it was some syntax errors that was giving me issues, but thanks for that clarification, makes things a lot clearer!

Answer (score 3):

`exists $hash{key}` says if the key exists, `defined $hash{key}` says if the key exists and its value is defined, `$hash{key}` says if the key exists and its value is true (see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood).